# Guide on how to communicate between 2 separate apps on two android devices

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development so please bear with my amateur skill set and use of terminologies. I want to basically create 2 apps, which will run on 2 different android devices, both are client apps but have somewhat different functionalities  (lets name the apps client1 and client2).

Client1 would send a specific message entered by the user1 to user2 who would have Client2. Client2 would show notification of the message on status bar once user2 connects to the internet. He will open the app which will show the message entered, which he will then confirm using some authentication method, and the data from the message sent by client1 to client2 will be used to run some queries on some sql database on the main server (separate).

How do i achieve this? Is there a specific tutorial for this (please bear in mind i am new to android development so if anything that would be easy to understand). Or is there some reference link that you could provide, or any previous question that might have what i am looking for? (I tried to search as much as i could but was not aware of the terminologies so i might have missed something) Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: First you have to decide how the apps will communicate. Are you going to use Bluetooth, HTTP, or some other protocol?

Comment: This is off topic for this site. But look into Firebase RealTime Database (https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/), I think that's the tool you're looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You said that you want the two apps to communicate via internet. You just answered yourself. Since you are new to android development start with learning firebase.

If you are using Android Studio, there is well documented Firebase Assistant built inside.

You can use it to connect the two apps. Use the 'Firebase notification service' to send custom notifications to any of the two apps.

For authenticating the message you can do a million things like adding a button or using some edit text in which user will enter some authentication code which will already be stored in your Firebase Database.

Then add another button which will either send the message received to your main server for running the queries or be stored in the second app.